# i cannot round up and get it for my GTIN

Tags: python

```
import random
r1 = (random.randint(0,9))
r2 = (random.randint(0,9))
r3 = (random.randint(0,9))
r4 = (random.randint(0,9))
r5 = (random.randint(0,9))
r6 = (random.randint(0,9))
r7 = (random.randint(0,9))
print ("your item barcode number is", r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7)
r8 = (r1*3+r2*1+r3*3+r4*1+r5*3+r6*1+r7*3)
roundup = round(r8, -1)
print (r8)
print(roundup)
  GTIN = (roundup-r8)
if GTIN<0:
GTIN = (r8-roundup) 
print("the GTIN number is", GTIN)
print(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,GTIN)
```

i can't get it to round up to the higher ten somebody help so basically i want it to be like 44 rounds up to 50 unless the number is a mutiple of 10 somebody help me do it

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_up_by_ten(num):
    return num if not num%10 else ((num//10)+1)*10
```

Comment: where do i put that in my code and what do i get rid of

Comment: This is a function, like `round`.  You would put this at the top of your code, under the `import`s.  Instead of calling `round(r8)` call `round_up_by_ten(r8)`.  If you're a little lost, I suggest the official python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html